# How to process a big XML File and selecting data from the same in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, azure-sql-database, xquery-sql

I have an XML parameter with the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ContactsGET xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <data>
        <Datum>
            <Owner>
                 <name>dilip.nair</name>
                 <id>3565223000000178021</id>
            </Owner>
            <Email xsi:type="xsd:string">mail2vembu@mail.com</Email>
            <Full_Name>Sridhar Vembu</Full_Name>
            <name>Abcon Group</name>
            <id>3565223000000206007</id>
        </Datum>
        <Datum>
            <Owner>
                 <name>dilip.nair</name>
                 <id>3565223000000178021</id>
            </Owner>
            <Email xsi:type="xsd:string">mail2vembu@mail.com</Email>
            <Full_Name>Sridhar Vembu</Full_Name>
            <name>Abcon Group</name>
            <id>3565223000000206007</id>
        </Datum>
    </data>
    <info>
         <per_page>200</per_page>
         <count>200</count>
         <page>1</page>
         <more_records>true</more_records>
    </info>
</ContactsGET>
```

In T-SQL I am trying to process each record under the *tag of Datum* in the XML.

```
SELECT 
    [TABLE].[ROW].value('Datum[1]','VARCHAR(4000)') 
FROM
    @pXMLGetContact.nodes('ContactsGET/data') AS [TABLE]([ROW]) 

SELECT @pXMLGetContact;
```

But the result set returns only the first record. The algorithm logic is insert the whole information into a table variable or temporary table and then process each record one by one. I have some business logic to implement record by record, how can I select as a whole record set.

I am using Azure SQL as my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your XML is living in a XML-typed variable you can try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<ContactsGET xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <data>
    <Datum>
      <Owner>
        <name>dilip.nair</name>
        <id>3565223000000178021</id>
      </Owner>
      <Email xsi:type="xsd:string">mail2vembu@mail.com</Email>
      <Full_Name>Sridhar Vembu</Full_Name>
      <name>Abcon Group</name>
      <id>3565223000000206007</id>
    </Datum>
    <Datum>
      <Owner>
        <name>dilip.nair</name>
        <id>3565223000000178021</id>
      </Owner>
      <Email xsi:type="xsd:string">mail2vembu@mail.com</Email>
      <Full_Name>Sridhar Vembu</Full_Name>
      <name>Abcon Group</name>
      <id>3565223000000206007</id>
    </Datum>
  </data>
  <info>
    <per_page>200</per_page>
    <count>200</count>
    <page>1</page>
    <more_records>true</more_records>
  </info>
</ContactsGET>'
```

--the query will pick the `<info>`-values directly from the XML as the seem to be once per XML. The values within `<data>` are picked by `.nodes()`, but one level deeper than you've tried it yourself (the repeating element is `<Datum>`):

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/ContactsGET/info/per_page/text())[1]','int') Info_PerPage
      ,@xml.value('(/ContactsGET/info/count/text())[1]','int') Info_Count
      ,@xml.value('(/ContactsGET/info/page/text())[1]','int') Info_Page
      ,@xml.value('(/ContactsGET/info/more_records/text())[1]','bit') Info_MoreRecords
      ,dat.value('(Owner/name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') Owner_name
      ,dat.value('(Owner/id/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') Owner_id
      ,dat.value('(Email/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') eMail
      ,dat.value('(Full_Name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') Full_Name
      ,dat.value('(name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') [Name]
      ,dat.value('(id/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') id
FROM @xml.nodes('/ContactsGET/data/Datum') A(dat);
```